# What is the significance of the opening scene of BlacKkKlansman

Tags: plot-explanation, blackkklansman

The opening scene shows wounded confederate soldiers lying on the ground.  The camera pulls back and upwards revealing more and more soldiers - as far as the eye can see.  A woman walks among them calling for a doctor by name - she appears to be looking for this doctor as though she expects him to be one of the wounded men.

This doesn't appear to be a battle ground - more like a safe place where the soldiers have returned to for treatment.

At first it appears that this could be a scene from an old movie - it's a bit grainy and in a boxy screen ratio - but the expanse of the scene and the camera movements make me suspect it's a modern shot.

What is the significance of this brief scene which takes place around 100 years before the events of the main story?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [a scene from another (famous) movie](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/life/movies/2018/08/19/how-spike-lee-blackkklansman-expertly-uses-gone-wind-shaft-cameos/1020950002/):

> *BlacKkKlansman* opens with a famous crane shot from the classic ***Gone
>   With the Wind***. Scarlett O’Hara (Vivien Leigh) roams through a train
>   yard full of Civil War injured and dead as a tattered Confederate flag
>   flaps in the breeze, the 1939 film's bow to a romanticized view of the
>   “Lost Cause.”

[QZ explains](https://qz.com/quartzy/1353571/spike-lees-blackkklansman-shows-white-supremacism-in-all-its-buffoonery-and-menace/):

> Spike Lee’s newest joint, *BlacKkKlansman*, opens with a scene from
>   another film: *Gone with the Wind*, the part when Vivien Leigh’s
>   character, Scarlett O’Hara, surveys the massive Confederate casualties
>   following the Battle of Atlanta—a resounding victory for the Union
>   that presaged the surrender of the slave-holding South less than a
>   year later.
>
> **It’s a hilarious barb to open the film with—a parameter-setting visual
>   gag that undermines the argument of white power before it even begins.
>   You fought a war 150 years ago and lost, Lee’s saying. Get over it.**
>   Everything that comes next makes the Confederate fanboys decades later
>   seem like genuine losers.
>
> **The opening also comes off as something of a dig at *Gone with the Wind*
>   itself**, whose reputation as one of the great films of all time took a
>   hit in the second half of the 20th century when modern film critics
>   and historians pointed out that, actually, it’s pretty racist and
>   nostalgic about the “Lost Cause” of the American Civil War—a
>   historical justification for [perpetuating white supremacism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_Cause_of_the_Confederacy).

[***Birth.Movies.Death.*** explains](https://birthmoviesdeath.com/2018/08/12/the-mirror-spike-lee-cinematic-racism-in-blackkklansman):

> **So much of *BlacKkKlansman*** – a genre movie that takes a recognizable storytelling mode (the "buddy cop" comedy) and remolds it to fit the revolutionary tale Lee is telling – **deals with the cinematic image, and how it acts as a mirror: reflecting and distorting both American history and its people throughout the medium’s just over 100-year lifetime.** There's a reason the very first scene we see in *BlacKkKlansman* wasn't even shot by Lee, but comes from Victor Fleming's heralded big screen adaptation of *Gone With the Wind* ('39). As the camera slowly pulls back over the battlefield of Atlanta, **it's a reminder that one of the earliest American cinematic "classics" celebrated a white Southern heroine who owned slaves and even lived under a charred symbol of racist pride: The Confederate Flag** (which fills up the majority of the first frame, defiantly flapping in the wind above hundreds of fallen Confederate soldiers).
>
> Upon its release, *Gone With the Wind* was a national sensation, with its opening date even declared a state holiday by Eurith D. Rivers, the Governor of Georgia. The most expensive film production yet attempted by an ever-expanding Hollywood, producer David O. Selznick feared he’d never see a profit. Instead – despite a nearly four-hour running time – *Gone With the Wind* grossed 25 times its cost on the movie’s initial run, and won eight Academy Awards, including Best Picture. **Adjusted for inflation, this Technicolor dream of the “Old South”** – which comes complete with Hattie McDaniel's Best Supporting Actress win for her portrayal of house servant, Mammy – **remains one of the biggest box office hits in US cinema history, and was named the fourth best American film by the AFI in ‘98.**
>
> Nevertheless, *Gone With the Wind* is still undeniably problematic, and has even been condemned by certain critics as being an antiquated relic that should go the way of the Confederate Flag. [As Lou Lumenick wrote in the *NY Post* back in '15](https://nypost.com/2015/06/24/gone-with-the-wind-should-go-the-way-of-the-confederate-flag/):
>
> > "True, *Gone with the Wind* isn’t as blatantly and virulently racist as D.W. Griffith’s *Birth of a Nation*, which was considered one of the greatest American movies as late as the early 1960s, but is now rarely screened, even in museums. **The more subtle racism of *Gone with the Wind* is in some ways more insidious, going to great lengths to enshrine the myth that the Civil War wasn’t fought over slavery — an institution the film unabashedly romanticizes."**

Here is Spike Lee talking to **BlackTree TV** on how he saw *Gone with the Wind* as a child and was disturbed by the movie: